# MongoDB partialFilterExpression for unique field with condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have User model in mongoose, this model has unique field `code` and it depends on another field `role`. The `code` field is `unique` if the `role` value is "agent".

This is my code field in model

```
   code: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        index: {
            unique: true,
            partialFilterExpression: { 'role' : {$in : ['manager']}}
        },
    },
```

`role` is simple string field

```
    role: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
```

Im expecting when i insert new user if user role is not "agent" then `code` field should insert null, it should only check the validation when `role` is "agent".

for example this data should valid and should inserted

```
{
   "name" : "John Doe",
   "role" : "manager",
   "code" : ""
}
```

But its throwing validation error

```
{"index":0,"code":11000,"keyPattern":{"code":1},"keyValue":{"code":""}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `partialFilterExpression: { 'role' : {$in : ['agent']}}` ?

Comment: with this change also the result is same.

Comment: Does the index create successfully? I think it doesn't accept `$in`.  Try `partialFilterExpression: { 'role' : 'agent'}`

Answer (score 0):

> [Partial indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/#partial-indexes) only index the documents in a collection that meet a specified filter expression.

The partialFilterExpression in the example `{ 'role' : {$in : ['manager']}}`, would mean that only managers are included in the index, and users are excluded.  This is the opposite of the description of what you are trying to do.

Since partialFilterExpressions do not support `$not`, you will need to list any *other* possible roles in the filter, like:
`{ 'role' : {$in : ['user']}}`